# The transfer map $H_*(BSO(3))\rightarrow H_*(BO(2))$: reference request

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, cohomology, invariant-theory, classifying-spaces

All cohomology and homology will be $Z/2$ coefficient. The restriction map
$H^*(BSO(3))\rightarrow H^*(BO(2))$ is well-known to be the inclusion of
the Dickson invariant $Z/2[w_2,w_3]$ into the symmetric polynomial algebra
$Z/2[w_1,w_2]$.  It is also well-known that the transfer $H^*(BO(2))
\rightarrow H^*(BSO(3))$ gives a section.

What is less known is the evaluation of the transfer, or the composition
$H^*(BO(2))\rightarrow H^*(BSO(3))\rightarrow H^*(BO(2))$, or the dual
$H_*(BO(2))\rightarrow H_*(BSO(3))\rightarrow H_*(BO(2))$.  Of course, this
follows easily from [Feshbach 
"The transfer and compact Lie groups" Transactions of the American Mathematical Society vol 251 (1979) pp.139-169.](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1977-83-03/S0002-9904-1977-14274-2/S0002-9904-1977-14274-2.pdf) Theorem II.11, and in cohomology one gets
$$f(x_1,x_2)\rightarrow f(x_1,x_2)+f_(x_1+x_2,x_2)+f(x_1+x_2,x_1)$$

By ``dualizing'' in homology one gets 
$$A(s)\cdot A(t)\rightarrow A(s)\cdot A(t) + A(s+t)\cdot (A(s)+A(t))$$
where we set $A(s)=\Sigma a_is^i$ with $a_i$ generator of $H_i(BO(1))$,
$A(X)=\Sigma _ia_iX^i$, and $\cdot$ denote s the "concatenation product''
$H_*(BO(1)^2)\rightarrow H_*(BO(2))$.

As I wrote, this is not difficult, but as we see so often $H^*(BSO(3))$ and
$H^*(BO(2))$ in the litterature, I feel that this should appear somewhere, but so far I haven't been able to find the reference.  Does anyone know if there is
any published reference of this?  Thank you very much in advance.